# Dynamically build external API URL and parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Today we have an object to keep track an external API usage like this:

```
const setParams = 
      (params) => Object.keys(params).map(
      (element) => element + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[element])).join('&') 

const API = {
    Common: {
        Search: (order) => `Common/Search?${setParams({order})}`,
    }}

console.log(API.Common.Search(1)); // "Common/Search?order=1"
```

However, we still get some typos what could be avoided.

Is it possible to dynamically set that URL even what we would need to change that API structure a bit?

```
const API = {
    Common: {
        Search: (order) => `${magicParent}/${magicCurrent}?${params}`,
        Another: (login, argA, argB) => `${magicParent}/${magicCurrent}?${magic(params)}`,
}}

console.log(API.Common.Search(1)); // "Common/Search?order=1"
console.log(API.Common.Another(1,2,3)); // "Common/Another?login=1&argA=2&argB=3"
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea | Not tested | Ugly (mutates):

```js
const isObject = // Implement yourself

const injectPath = (obj, path = '') => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach( ([key, value]) => {
    if (isObject(value) {
       injectPath(value, path + '/' + key;
    } else {
      // It is a function
      obj[key] = value(path);
    }
  })
}

const API = injectPath({
    Common: {
        Search: (path) => (order) => `${path}?${setParams({order})}`,
    }}
});
```